# Правильна форма слова "відповідять"

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання

Згідно з логікою дієвідмінювання, слово *відповідати* в 3-й особі множини майбутнього часу доконаного виду має перетворитись на *відповідять*. Але звучить це трохи дивно і смішно.

Чи є така форма правильною, та чи існують інші форми цього дієслова окрім очевидного *дадуть відповідь*?

Comment: Є ще такі запитання: [1](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/392/4), [2](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/504/4). Здається, це «defective verb» — він має лише частину форм. (Хоча в деяких діалектах/говірках форм більше, але в цілому по Україні єдиного варіанту для деяких форм немає.)

Comment: @Sasha - Історично форми _[відпо]вісти_ мали такі самі закінчення, як і дієслово _їсти_, бо обидва належать до т.з. класу нетематичних дієслів, закінчення в них приєднуються безпосередньо до кореня. В слов’янських мовах їх усього 5 (бути, дати, їсти, [відпо]вісти, та імати [імам, імаш] – цей останній у нас тут випав), впізнаються вони по закінченню _-м_ в 1 ос. одн. тепер. ч.: _відповім - їм, відповіси - їси, відповімо - їмо, відповідять - їдять_, тому (а історично так і було) наказ. спос. 2 ос. одн. має бути як _іж!_, тобто _відповіж!_ Це абсолютно орґанічна форма й є в инш. слов’ян. мовах.

Comment: @YellowSky, було б добре, якби Ви це додали в ті питання як відповідь. Бо думка розумна, навіть на мій погляд, логічніша, ніж деякі речі, що там зараз як відповіді оформлені, але, як коментар, вона менш помітна. Хоча це, звісно, на Ваш розсуд. (Іще добре було б її підкріпити вказівкою на те, що [навіть в правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par80p7) «їсти» і «…вісти» винесені в одну окрему групу поза дієвідмінами.)

Comment: @Sasha - Я сам думав написати й напишу, тільки це розлога тема, там требя з ятями та реконструйованими змінами звуків писати, посидіти треба, я на вихідних напишу. Там у вас у питанні #2 запитувач сам пише про це, перелічує й видатних письменників, які так писали

Comment: За старою інститутською системою за «відповідять» ви б отримали -6 балів на диктанті. «Вони відповідатимуть довго» або «вони нададуть відповідь через деякий час», так можна сказати.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Найголовніше: дієслово **доконаного** виду — це *відповісти*, а *відповідати* — це дієслово **недоконаного** виду.

*відповідати* – [дієслово **недоконаного** виду](https://sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

| МАЙБУТНІЙ ЧАС | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 особа | відповіда́тиму | відповіда́тимемо, відповіда́тимем |
| 2 особа | відповіда́тимеш | відповіда́тимете |
| 3 особа | відповіда́тиме | відповіда́тимуть |

*відповіcти* – [дієслово **доконаного** виду](https://sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

| МАЙБУТНІЙ ЧАС | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 особа | відповім | відповімо |
| 2 особа | відповіси | відповісте |
| 3 особа | відповiсть | [відповідять] |

Щодо останньої форми *відповідять*, то саме цей словник, [УЕМІФ НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), твердить, що вона взагалі не утворюється, тобто «небажана», хоча инші словники, наприклад «Українська літературна вимова і наголос», 1973, тієї ж у принципі Академії Наук, цю форму наводить серед инших як правильну. Або ось, [Інформаційно-пошукова система "Український правопис"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170118203510/http://pravopys.kiev.ua/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=2569) теж каже, що *відповідять* – це нормально. Перевірте самі, це [§ 80.7](http://pravopys.net/#search=80-85).

Щодо використання форми "відповідять", можна перевірити у корпусі ГРАК: вона [використовується зараз і в використовувалась в минулому](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac17a&tab=advanced&keyword=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&attrs=word%2Csemtag%2Ctag&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&glue=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.title&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A8712%7D%5D).

Comment: Ем... чому не дотримуєтесь діючих правил і пишете _инші_?

Comment: @BohdanKuts - Скажімо так: не я теперіні діючі правила складав, я вважаю, що правила, які раніше були такими самими діючими, точніші, бо й я, й усі скрізь кажуит саме _**и**нші_. До того ж, тут питання зовсім не про це слово. :)

Comment: "І" з крапочкою та "Є" з язычком пішли від чортів

Comment: @RomanMikhol - Та ви що, так-таки від чортів, а зовсім не з грецької абетки?

Comment: @Sútnôstj, http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=відповідати і http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=відповісти — це були посилання на таблиці відмінювання, а не на тлумачення (отой словник електрозварювання ElWelding використовувався як спосіб послатися на конкретну сторінку словника ULIF). Можливо, тепер варто послатися на корінь https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua або на якісь неофіційні дзеркала на кшталт https://goroh.pp.ua/Словозміна/відповідати і https://goroh.pp.ua/Словозміна/відповісти. А може, і так непогано…

Answer (score -1):

Відповістимуть.
Мовознавці, імовірно, так не вважають, але в розмовній українській це слово зустрічається. І звучить не так «дивно і смішно», як «відповідять».

Comment: Я б не сказав, що тут взагалі щось смішно, не кажучи вже про те, що ставити дієслова доконаного виду в майбутній композитний стан взагалі не можна. Що, _*написатимуть, *стрибнутимуть, *впастимуть, *сістимуть_? Це ж покручи, вони не смішні. А _відповідять_ - це орґанічне слово,  _відповім - їм, відповіси - їси, відповімо - їмо, відповідять - їдять_ — що тут смішного? Це **норма**, а норма вона об’єктивна, не смішна ні з якого боку,

Comment: Автор запитання теж вважає, що «відповідять» звучить «трохи дивно і смішно».  
Я написав у відповіді, що моя відповідь — не відповідь мовознавця. Як натуральний українець, не вважаю «відповістимуть» та інші подібні слова покручами. Нормальні слова.

Comment: Хоча… Слова на -муть більш характерні для недоконаного виду: писатимуть, стрибатимуть, падатимуть, сідатимуть, відповідатимуть. Тому у доконаному виді правильно має бути напишуть, стрибнуть, впадуть, сядуть, відповідять. Думаю над тим, чи не видалити тепер свою відповідь взагалі, оскільки сам тепер вважаю її неправильною.

Comment: Думаю, що видаляти не варто, ми тут усе про неї обговорили, а може й знайдеться хтось, в кого в родині так і говорили, то збагатіємося знанням. ;) Мінусувати за таке ніхто не буде.

Comment: Приклади вживання: http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=відповістимуть